# Group similar rows and pivot grouped data into new associative elements

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an original data array as follows

```
$data = [
                [
                    "content" => "Niche description 1",
                    "type" => "niche_des"
                ],
                [
                    "content"  => "Niche description 2",
                    "type" => "niche_des"
                ],
                [
                    "content" => "Niche description 3",
                    "type" => "niche_des"
                ],
                [
                    "content" => "Product description 1",
                    "type" => "product_des"
                ],
                [
                    "content" => "Product description 2",
                    "type" => "product_des"
                ],
                [
                    "content" => "Product description 3",
                    "type" => "product_des"
                ],
                [
                    "content" => "Trust site description 1",
                    "type" => "trust_site"
                ],
                [
                    "content" => "Trust site description 2",
                    "type" => "trust_site"
                ],
                [
                    "content" => "Trust site description 3",
                    "type" => "trust_site"
                ]
            ];
```

I tried to put the data into a new array like this, but it didn't work

This is the result I want

```
$newdata = [
                [
                    "niche_des" => "Niche description 1",
                    "product_des" => "Product description 1",
                    "trust_site" => "Trust site description 1"
                ],
                [
                    "niche_des" => "Niche description 2",
                    "product_des" => "Product description 2",
                    "trust_site" => "Trust site description 2"
                ],
                [
                    "niche_des" => "Niche description 3",
                    "product_des" => "Product description 3",
                    "trust_site" => "Trust site description 3"
                ],
            ];
```

I tried handling it this way

```
$newdata = [];
foreach ($data as $des) {
    if ($des->type == 'niche_des') {
        $niche = $des->content;
    }
    if ($des->type == 'product_des') {
        $product_d = $des->content;
    }
    if ($des->type == 'trust_site') {
        $trust_site = $des->content;
    }
    array_push($newdata, [
        'niche_des' => $niche,
        'product_des' => $product_d,
        'trust_site' => $trust_site
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand damn thing. How did you match "Content niche 4" and "Content product 1" in the same array and also others. It would probably be better if you explain your intention clearly and share some data which will make more sense.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you
My wish is to put the data into an object consisting of the corresponding key and value {
    "niche_des": "Content niche 1",
    "product_des": "Content product 1",
    "video": "Content video 1",
    "image": "Content image 1",
    "trust_site": "Content trust 1"
 }

Comment: I have adjusted my question, hope you understand it better

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues with your code that I can see:

1. You are trying to use object access notation (`->`) to access an array. You need to use array access notation (`['...']`).
2. You are not counting the array elements properly.

Because you have said in the comments that the data may not always be the same, this two-step process is the way I would handle it:

Step 1. Split the original array by type:

```
$tempdata = [];
foreach ($data as $des) {
    if (!isset($tempdata[$des['type']])) {
        $tempdata[$des['type']] = [];
    }

    $tempdata[$des['type']][] = $des['content'];
}
```

`$tempdata` will now look like this:

```
[
    "niche_des" => [
        "Niche description 1",
        "Niche description 2",
        "Niche description 3",
    ],
    "product_des" => [
        "Product description 1",
        "Product description 2",
        "Product description 3",
    ],
    "trust_site" => [
        "Trust site description 1"
        "Trust site description 2"
        "Trust site description 3"
    ],
];
```

Step 2. Rebuild the above split array into the format you want.

```
$newdata = [];
$types = array_keys($tempdata);
$itemcount = count($tempdata[$types[0]]);

for ($i = 0; $i < $itemcount; $i++) {
    $item = [];

    foreach ($types as $type) {
        $item[$type] = $tempdata[$type][$i];
    }

    $newdata[] = $item;
}
```

**Important:** The above solution requires the following two conditions to be true:

1. There are always the same number of elements of each type.
2. They elements are already in the correct order (i.e. `niche_des` #1 matches `product_des` #1 and `trust_site` #1).

Comment: Thank you

Since my data is not fixed, not always = 3
So I want to rely on the key 'type' to handle it, do you have any solution for me

Answer (score -1):

You can use a number of techniques to isolate the trailing integer of each `content` column value (I'll demontrate `ltrim()`ing letters and spaces ...and six irrelevant symbols on the [ascii table](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html)).  Group on that integer, push your desired data into each group, then after the loop finishes, remove the temporary grouping key by calling `array_values()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZGiMS))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $result[ltrim($row['content'], 'A..z ')][$row['type']] = $row['content'];
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'niche_des' => 'Niche description 1',
    'product_des' => 'Product description 1',
    'trust_site' => 'Trust site description 1',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'niche_des' => 'Niche description 2',
    'product_des' => 'Product description 2',
    'trust_site' => 'Trust site description 2',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'niche_des' => 'Niche description 3',
    'product_des' => 'Product description 3',
    'trust_site' => 'Trust site description 3',
  ),
)
```

Comment: @Bien if this doesn't work for your actual project data, then your question is Unclear.